# How do I activate the side quest in the Inverted Arbor?

Tags: made-in-abyss-binary-star

The map for the Inverted Arbor in the Abyss 2nd Layer has a side quest near the entrance to the Corpse-Weeper Den. I've explored both the upper catwalks and the lower islands near the spot indicated by the map, but the side quest won't activate.

How do I activate the side quest in the Inverted Arbor?

[image: Inverted Arbor side quest marker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you by chance happen to have the Ecology Survey subquest? Check the quest tab - if that is the case, you are searching for some specific creature.

Hint 1:

> which you probably can't find because the 2d map makes you assume they are *above* when you should look *below* instead

Hint 2:

> either climb down or enter the zone from the Edge of the Abyss and you should be at the right level

Comment: I had the Ecology Investigation subquest but not Ecology Survey. I checked out the [the area below the quest marker](https://i.imgur.com/nWmTxse.png). Initially nothing happened. The quest didn't trigger until I ran around for a bit and fought a few squirrels.